# How to query sql data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database

How do I query data from multiple tables.
Example:

I want to get all info for main_id 1.
Basically the brand, category, model and SN in a single query.

**main_table**

```
id brand category model sn
1....1....2........1....1
2....2....1........3....2
3....2....4........5....3
```

**brand_table**

```
id....name....main_fk
1....Apple....1
2....Sony.....3
```

**Category_table**

```
id....name.........main_fk
1....Electronics...1
2....Furniture.....4
```

**Model_table**

```
id....name....main_fk
1....Iphone5..1
2....GoPro3...2
```

**SN_table**

```
id....name....main_fk
1....SN1......1
2....SN2......2
```

Comment: Defiantly you need to join tables on the basis of some PK an FK.

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
SELECT bt.name as brand, ct.name as category, mt.name as model, sn.name as sn
FROM main_tbl as maint
INNER JOIN brand_table as bt ON bt.main_fk = maint.id
INNER JOIN category_table as ct ON ct.main_fk = maint.id
INNER JOIN model_table as mt ON mt.main_fk = maint.id
INNER JOIN SN_table as sn ON sn.main_fk = maint.id
```

For more info about `INNER JOIN`: [INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)

Comment: where did you get bt.name? Is that a new variable you just created?

Comment: you can make alias of table

Comment: did you try this query? **bt** in `bt.name` is **alias of brand_table**

Comment: It works now... could you explain this part. I want to know how you did it.
Sorry, I am new to mysql.

1) SELECT bt.name as brand
2) FROM main_tbl as maint
3) INNER JOIN brand_table as bt ON bt.main_fk = maint.id

Comment: You can check from this link and learn also: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: you can accept answer if you got what you want, so other users can take help